# Drag-and-Dropped Row's Parent Element is Null

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, draggable

I have two tables. The client should be able to drag and drop each table's row. They can either drop the row into a new position on the current table, or add the row to a specific position on the other table.

I'm able to insert the new row into the desired position on either table (and delete the original), but when I try to drag-and-drop that element a second time, it's parent element comes back as null, preventing me from repeating the drag-and-drop function a second time.

I need to solve this with pure, vanilla javascript.

```
//Table Structure (there are two of these, I'm trying to save space here)
<table id="thisTable" class="dropzone">
  <thead>
     ...
  </thead>
  <tbody id="thisBody">
     <tr id="123" class="drag-row draggable="true">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr id="124" class="drag-row draggable="true">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

//Collect Variables from the original row, the target table and the row being dropped into.

//Code to Insert New Row
function addRow(table_id, copy_id, target_id) {

    let targetRow =document.getElementById(target_id);
    let targetIndex = targetRow.rowIndex;
    let copyRow = document.getElementById(copyId); // find row to copy
    let targetTable = document.getElementById(tableID); // find table to append to
    let clone = copyRow.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
    //clone.id = "newID"; // change id or other attributes/contents
    //table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table
//targetTable.children[1].insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", clone);

    // Insert a row at desired index
    let newRow = targetTable.insertRow(targetIndex);
    newRow.id = clone.id;
    newRow.draggable = "true";
    newRow.classList.add("drag-row");
    newRow.innerHTML = clone.innerHTML;

}

//Code to delete original row
dragSrcEl.remove();
```

I don't think I'll need to add in all the drag-and-drop code, because those seem to be working fine (when the parent element of the inserted node isn't null).

I've gone through a couple questions similar to this one and it seems that some commands in vanilla create new elements without tying them to the DOM? Supposedly by using the append() command you could add a new row to a table without disconnecting it from the DOM, but I tried that and got no result.

Which of the commands I'm using above would disconnect the newly inserted row from the DOM?

Is there a safe way, in vanilla js, to copy the contents of a row and inserted into a specific index of another (or the same table)?

It's frustrating because I finally got the code working... once.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I forgot to add the necessary event listeners to the newly inserted row, that would explain why drag-and-drop stopped working for them :)